# Using KVC's @count on an array throws an exception from the class that's in the array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, key-value-coding

So, I have this:

```
@interface Foo
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSArray* bars;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize bars = _bars;
// ... more stuff here ...
@end
```

So `Foo` fills up `bars` with instances of `Bar`, and the instance of `Foo` lives in a container object.  And then I say:

```
[container valueForKeyPath:@"foo.bars.@count"]
```

Which I expect to give me a nice boxed number.  However I instead get:

```
Exception: [<Bar 0xc175b70> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bars.
```

So, why?  I wouldn't expect to have to implement anything special on `Bar` to make an `NSArray` of `Bar`s countable, but that's what this error message is implying.  The documentation only has trivial examples, but I would expect this to just work in the same manner.

Comment: For whatever reason, `@"foo"` is returning an object of type `Bar`, not of type `Foo`. Are you sure you haven't made an error in your hierarchy?

Comment: Agreed, what's your implementation of the container object look like?

Comment: The container just has a @synthesize for Foo: `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) Foo* foo;`  Furthermore, if I create an accessor for bars like this: `-(NSArray*)bars { return _bars }` and set a breakpoint on it, it gets hit during the KVC operation, right before the exception is thrown.

Comment: And if I say `@"foo.someInteger"` that works just fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does my code differ from yours? Because this works...

```
//  Foo.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Foo : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSArray* bars;
@end


//  Foo.m
#import "Foo.h"

@interface Foo ()
// extended property decl here, to be readable, but this didn't seem to matter in my test
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray* bars;
@end


@implementation Foo

- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _bars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"bar one", @"bar none", nil];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then, in my container class:

```
// .h
@property (strong, nonatomic) Foo *foo;

// .m
_foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
NSNumber *c = [self valueForKeyPath:@"foo.bars.@count"];
NSLog(@"count is %@", c);
```

Logs => "count is 2"

Comment: Okay, I'm just going to say this is the right answer because it's answers my question which is to say, "It should work."  So, I need to debug.  Obviously there is a lot more code in my project than what I've included.  I thought I had boiled it down to the bare minimum, but obviously something unexpected is going on.